# Property $\mathcal{P}$ of group such that all subgroups of that group have $\mathcal{P}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

Suppose $\mathcal{P}$ is a property of groups such that if a group $G$ has $\mathcal{P}$, then all subgroups of $G$ have $\mathcal{P}$. Given that $G$ is poly-$\mathcal{P}$, I'm trying to show that every subgroup $H \leq G$ is poly-$\mathcal{P}$.

Since $G$ is poly-$\mathcal{P}$, we know that there exists a series of subgroups 
$$1 = G_0 \vartriangleleft G_1 \vartriangleleft \ldots \vartriangleleft G_n = G$$
such that all factors $\frac{G_{i+1}}{G_i}$ have $\mathcal{P}$.

My idea was to consider the series
$$1 = H_0 \vartriangleleft H_1 \vartriangleleft \ldots \vartriangleleft H_n = H$$
where $H_i = H \cap G_i$. I've tried to show that $\frac{H_{i+1}}{H_i}$ can be written as a subgroup of $\frac{G_{i+1}}{G_i}$ by using the second isomorphism theorem:
we know that $G_i \vartriangleleft G_{i+1}$ and $G_{i+1} \cap H \leq G_{i+1}$, since $G_{i+1}\cap H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Hence we have the following equalities:
$$\frac{G_{i+1}\cap H}{G_i \cap H} = \frac{G_{i+1}\cap H}{G_i \cap H \cap G_{i+1}} \cong \frac{G_i(G_{i+1}\cap H)}{G_i} \leq \frac{G_{i+1}}{G_i}$$
and since $\frac{G_{i+1}}{G_i}$ has $\mathcal{P}$, so does $\frac{G_i(G_{i+1}\cap H)}{G_i}$.

Is this argument valid?

Comment: Just use the Second Isomorphism Theorem. $H_{i+1}/H_i=(H \cap G_{i+1})/(H \cap G_i) \cong (H \cap G_{i+1})G_i/G_i$.

Comment: so what I wrote is valid? (I was editing my question while you answered it I suppose...)

Comment: Yes what you wrote is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

The English could be improved upon slightly though. For instance, when you wrote

> Hence we have the following equalities:

you proceeded to list just one equality, an isomorphism, and a subgroup relation. This is nitpicking though.

It's a good proof!